# Selecting from dropdown menu with Playwright in Python using attributes

Tags: python, web-scraping, playwright

With Playwright in Python I am trying to select from a variation dropdown on an Amazon product page -> https://www.amazon.de//dp/B08XWKDGL7

```
\<select name="dropdown_selected_size_name" autocomplete="off" data-a-touch-header="Größe" id="native_dropdown_selected_size_name" tabindex="0" data-action="a-dropdown-select" class="a-native-dropdown a-declarative"\>

    <option value="0,B08XWN4HM6" class="dropdownAvailable" data-a-css-class="dropdownAvailable" id="native_size_name_0" data-a-id="size_name_0" data-a-html-content="4,0 x 30 mm 500 Stück"> 4,0 x 30 mm 500 Stück </option>           
    <option value="1,B08XWKDGL7" class="dropdownAvailable" data-a-css-class="dropdownAvailable" id="native_size_name_1" data-a-id="size_name_1" data-a-html-content="4,0 x 35 mm 500 Stück"> 4,0 x 35 mm 500 Stück </option>           
    <option value="2,B08XWMK3H7" class="dropdownAvailable" data-a-css-class="dropdownAvailable" id="native_size_name_2" data-a-id="size_name_2" data-a-html-content="4,0 x 40 mm 500 Stück"> 4,0 x 40 mm 500 Stück </option>           
    <option value="3,B08XWKG8PN" class="dropdownAvailable" data-a-css-class="dropdownAvailable" id="native_size_name_3" data-a-id="size_name_3" data-a-html-content="4,0 x 45 mm 300 Stück"> 4,0 x 45 mm 300 Stück </option>           
    <option value="4,B08XWMYH3Z" class="dropdownAvailable" data-a-css-class="dropdownSelect" id="native_size_name_4" 
    [...]       

\</select\>
```

I am able to select the various options by the index (except the 1st option with `index=0`) using the following code:

```
from playwright.sync_api import sync_playwright

url = 'https://www.amazon.de//dp/B08XWKDGL7'

with sync_playwright() as p: 
    browser = p.firefox.launch()
    page = browser.new_page() 
    page.goto(url)  
    html = page.content()
    page.select_option('//select[@name="dropdown_selected_size_name"]',  index=1)
    browser.close()
```

However I would like to select the option by using the attribute: `data-a-html-content="4,0 x 40 mm 500 Stück"`. I am using the following code:

```
page.select_option('//select[@name="dropdown_selected_size_name"]', '//option[@data-a-html-content="4,0 x 35 mm 500 Stück"]')
```

Then I get the following error message. I get the same error message when I choose other attributes, e.g. `data-a-id="size_name_3"`.

```
playwright._impl._api_types.TimeoutError: Timeout 30000ms exceeded.
=========================== logs ===========================
waiting for selector "//select[@name="dropdown_selected_size_name"]"
  selector resolved to visible <select tabindex="0" autocomplete="off" data-a-touch-hea…>…</select>
  selecting specified option(s)
    did not find some options - waiting... 
============================================================
```

Please advise, why is this not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In playwright, there are three alternatives to select dropdown element

```
1.  select by label

2. select by index

3.  select by value
```

You can select dropdown element by visible text(label) or by value instead and select dropdow element by attribute is not supported in playwright even not in Selenium too.

**Example:**

```
from playwright.sync_api import sync_playwright

with sync_playwright() as p:
    browser = p.firefox.launch()
    page = browser.new_page() 
    page.goto(url)  
    page.locator('//select[@name="dropdown_selected_size_name"]').select_option(label="4,0 x 30 mm 500 Stück")
    #page.locator('//select[@name="dropdown_selected_size_name"]').select_option(value="B08XWN4HM6")
    page.wait_for_timeout(4000)
    browser.close()
```